# Proving $\int_0^{4/\pi} 3x^2\sin(1/x)-x\cos(1/x)\mathrm dx=\frac{32\sqrt{2}}{\pi^3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

The integral is again
$$
\int_0^{4/\pi} 3x^2\sin(1/x)-x\cos(1/x)\mathrm dx=\frac{32\sqrt{2}}{\pi^3}
$$
I found this in an old calc book and am really lost as to where to start and am intrigued by the cool looking analytic solution. Is it possible to use a Laplace transform? I am not really familiar with the technique.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want the upper endpoint to be $4/\pi$, not $\pi/4$.

Comment: oops yes i do, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite simple
$$\text{integral} =x^3\sin\frac{1}{x}\big|_{0}^{\frac{4}{\pi}}=\frac{32\sqrt{2}}{\pi^3}$$

Comment: ha, I suppose it is.

Comment: the $3x^2$ is a tip off.

Comment: I see that now, of course :). I even tried to tackle them separately to start

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try an integration by parts on one of the terms.